# How to set up game engine publishing (cross-platform) addon?

Tags: game-engine, export

I need to export a game runtime using Blender in Linux, that can run in Windows. In other words, from Blender in Linux, I need to export the game as an .exe with accompanying files etc., such that when the whole folder is copied to windows, the game can be run.

I have done a lot of searching, and I know that the add-on called "Game Engine Publishing" should let me export a game engine runtime for multiple operating systems. I found [this wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/Publishing) about the add-on that says this:

> Out of the box, this addon can only publish using the "default" platform, which makes use of the Blender binary used to run the addon. In order to publish to other platforms you will need to download extra binaries. The simplest way to do this is to download the binaries for the platforms you wish to publish to and extract them into your Lib Path (//lib by default). From here the Auto Add Platforms operator (found under the platforms drop-down menu) can be used to automatically setup platforms for the binaries in your Lib Path.

But I'm embarrassed to say that I don't know what it means by "downloading the extra binaries," and despite a lot of googling and stackexchange searching, I haven't been able to find a simple answer. Could somebody please help me or point me to some resources on this?

Also, one possible complication is that I'm exporting the game from a high-performance computing environment where I don't have admin, so I'm not sure if I can add files to directories higher up than my home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the arrow pointing down below the platforms label, there should be a button to automatically download and install them for you. Alternatively you can download them manually from www.blender.org, basically just download blender for windows/mac (zip version) and extract them on the //lib folder.

However, if you really are looking for a profesional way to publish your game, avoid using the addon at all, use a launcher instead. BGECore comes with a ready-to-use launcher: https://github.com/elmeunick9/BGECore/tree/master/tools/Simple%20Launcher

Comment: Thank you. The auto-download button did not work within the high-performance computing environment (which is a weird case), but I downloaded the .zip files from Blender.org and put them in the //lib folder. I also realized that you can manually set the library folder to be something other than //lib, which is good in this case since it's a weird file structure. I'll look at BGECore later, thanks for the mention. But right now I'm just trying to debug and test.